# How to see a cron job which is running right now on server?

Tags: batch-file, cron, webserver

I have set several batch file in cron and few cron jobs runs for a hour.

I want to see which cron job is running right now and what is its status. Is it possible to watch it.

Thanks

Comment: and I have a cron which has `*/5 * * * *` . does it mean five time a hour?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to see what processes are running by typing `ps -aux` in your console. You can also use utility like `top` which shows You what processes are running in realtime.